# Python: MODBUS Communication failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus

I'am trying to communicate with a MODBUS controller that has internal and external BUS, so there are MASTER and SLAVE modes. I cant read anything from it with MinimalModbus or Modbus-tk. But it reads and works with manufactors own modbus tool.

I have been using MinimalModbus and Modbus-tk successfully with other devices that are for sure in  SLAVE MODE, but i just can't get anything from that controller. I wonder what i could try here?

Comment: This might be a frame timing issue, i.e. the controller replies too early or too late. You could try using other Modbus communication tools, like [unserver](https://unserver.xyz/) or simplymodbus and see if they work or throw a particular error.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you can use the manufacturer Modbus program correctly, I'd suggest using a sniffer to catch the packets of that communication. For Modbus TCP you could use Wireshark, for RTU you could use HHD Software serial port monitor.

If you think the controller is a master, you can also try with a slave simulator that shows you if a master is connected and the requests. For example ModRSsim on Sourceforge.

Comment: Here are some logs with HHD Software monitor and Modbus view module. First is CAS Modbus scanners request that gets answered and Packet 149 is Modbus-tk, that looks identical, but no answer. http://pastebin.com/nwPLBL5K And Pure packet viewer module logs, reading same aadress, same way, as before. cas log: http://pastebin.com/2jjRwELw  modbus-tk failed log: http://pastebin.com/5uNx9TAn

Comment: Seeing the first log, the message is the same, as you say, including the CRC. Maybe it's some issues with timing? The timeout of modbus-tk, or the time between polls? I'm not sure.